# Why process is not getting killed?

Tags: process, window, taskkill

I have a process in Window, which is process of our own product. Problem is my process is not getting killed.

Product having exe of process is already got uninstalled successfully. So, exe no longer exists still you can see process running in task manager.

I tried all the tools including task manager, process explorer, taskkill, ntsd, but nothing seems to work.

When I check in process explorer, it owns one handle, and even I am not able to close that handle.

Please see image below for more clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you running the cmd.exe as administrator. Then try to force kill the process including all the processes related to it, by typing in command prompt "taskkill /im  /f /t". For ex. "taskkill /im notepad.exe /f /t".